# How to charge a 2200 µF capacitor to 59 V in around 100 ms from a 12 V battery?

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, charging

I need to charge a 2200 µF capacitor to 59 V in around 100 ms from a 12 V battery. This converter needs to be at most 35 mm wide.

This requires the use of either a boost converter or a DC-DC flyback converter. Most commercial boost converters online are rated for up to around 40 V. Most 60 V flyback converters are too big to fit.

I initially wanted to design my own flyback DC-DC converter using an ATtiny85 (will this suffice or do I have to use a dedicated converter IC?) which takes 12 V, 5 A input and outputs 59 V, 1 A.

Are there any existing converters that already satisfy these conditions?

---

Bobflux's solution:
[image]

Comment: How often does the charging need to happen? You mention a width restriction, not length or height. You could consider charging a larger capacitor slowly and using it to supply most of the the necessary 5A for 0.1s. Depending on how long you have to re-charge the big cap, your main boost converter maybe doesn't need to be that beefy.

Comment: Thinking of power consumption. What is the repetition rate of the charge cycle. If you don't have to do this very often there may be scope to overdrive the converter for 100ms.

Comment: With a boost converter, you have a diode between input and output. So if the capacitor is completely discharged at the beginning, uncontrolled current will flow from the power supply to charge it to 12V. How do you wish to handle the charging part from 0V to 12V? Limit current? Is it critical, or does the cap never discharge below 12V, so it never has to be charged back, so it can be done slowly? Or is the cap discharged to 0V every time and thus needs to be recharged all the way to 59V with proper handling of the 0V to 12V part?

Comment: @danmcb Ideally, the capacitor will be discharged immediately after it is charged. The height restriction is 50mm, and length 200mm.

Comment: @RoyC The repetition rate will depend on other factors, but I think that it will be frequent enough that overdriving the converter would be dangerous

Comment: @bobflux The capacitor will be fully discharged to 0V. To handle the 0V-12V, limiting current seems like the obvious option, unless there is better way.

Comment: If it's a COTS 2200 μF capacitor, bear in mind the tolerance on that value.

Comment: Is there any chance of getting five 12 V batteries in series?

Comment: Five 12V batteries in series would be too bulky and expensive I think. I only need the 59v for a very short period of time, so, I think a capacitor is probably more fitting for this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding a second answer specifically for this circuit.

I thought about controlling a converter with an Attiny and the huge inductor that this implies, and felt a bit of nostalgia, so I designed an analog solution with a bit more "modern" performance.

[image]

**Bird's eye view:**

This is a hysteretic buck boost that regulates the inductor current and keeps it inside a specific range. The center of the range is the desired 5A average current, and the width of the range is the hysteresis. Basically, when the inductor current is too low, we turn on the MOSFET, and when current is too high, we turn it off. It's the simplest control algorithm possible, it's inherently stable, it doesn't need a clock, it has built-in overcurrent protection, etc.

- It's a 4 switch buck boost, with 2 FETs and 2 diodes.
- Control signals at the bottom right (Buck and Boost) activate both phases.

**Details:**

To make a hysteretic DC-DC converter we need to measure inductor current, feed it to a comparator with hysteresis, and drive the MOSFET.

"Measuring inductor current" is a bit more complicated than usual here, because both ends of the inductor are going to switch with large voltage swings: the left side in  buck mode, the right side in boost mode.

It is much more convenient to sense the current in a place without too much voltage swing.

Thus, Q1,2,3,4,5 and associated passive components form a multitasking high and low side current sense amplifier.

On top we have a current mirror (Q1-Q3, suggest BCM857) so the emitters of both transistors are at the same potential. When a voltage drop appears on R5 due to the current we want to sense, current in R2 and R6 will thus be different, Q3 outputs this on its collector, which controls Q5, which applies feedback and zeros the voltage difference between the emitters of Q1 and Q3.

A side effect is that an image of the current we want to measure, which is IL, is output on the collector of Q5 and converted into a voltage by R8. Thus:

\$ V_\text{R8} = I_L \cdot \frac{\text{R5}}{\text{R6}} \cdot \text{R8} \$, i.e. we get about 1V/A on R8.

When MOSFET X1 is off, current flows through R11 instead. Now Q2 and Q4 stop pretending to be a current mirror for biasing the previous circuit, and instead take an active role and forward the voltage drop measured on R11 as current to the previous circuit, which outputs it. This mode will have higher offset voltage, which is not important because the boost phase is only a small part of the whole process.

Thus we have an image of the inductor current on R8.

The comparator does its job, with hysteresis, and generates the driving signals for the MOSFETs.

The "6.3V" source on the comparator input corresponds to the target current. By varying this voltage, average current can be adjusted.

The logic gates direct the signals to the appropriate MOSFET. The buck FET will need a bootstrapped driver, the boost FET is low-side so a simple low-side driver chip will do.

The OR gate ensures the buck FET stays on during the boost phase, otherwise the circuit would disconnect itself from the power supply.

The "Buck" signal works as global enable, and "Boost" is generated by a function source used as comparator, enabling the boost phase when output voltage is >12V and disabling it when the target voltage is reached.

Without inductor losses, estimated efficiency is around 93% so it's pretty neat for such a simple circuit.

With the part numbers shown, it will oscillate around 150kHz. This is pretty much as fast as the old LM393 can go. To shrink the inductor further, a faster comparator is needed. Most fast comparators run on 5V so a bit of scaling of resistor values would be needed.

It charges the 2200µF cap in 70ms. It should charge it a bit faster with a faster comparator, because excessive comparator delay from LM393 lets IL drop a little too much at high output voltage.

Most of the losses are in the MOSFETs, especially switching losses in the boost MOSFET which requires the most care. Using a larger inductor value reduces switching frequency and thus switching losses, but it increases inductor losses.

Here is a [link to the simulation file](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/aig9nc6fatuuvir9h2ywa/buckboost-2.cir?rlkey=lgi1bhjhy47nvuqamr7i649wi&dl=0) which you can use with [Microcap](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152171/discussion-on-answer-by-bobflux-how-to-charge-a-2200-f-capacitor-to-59-v-in-aro); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

You're making some unwarranted assumptions about the methods of charging.

Start from a simple energy balance. 2200 uF at 59 V stores 0.5CV<sup>2</sup> = 3.83 joules.

If you want to deliver that energy in 100 ms, then the average output power during that time is 38 watts, or a little over 3 amps from 12 volts. If you factor in losses, then you would probably need to draw 4 or 5 amps during the charging process.

If you want to limit your peak power draw from the 12 V battery, then you need a converter that can work at constant power into a varying voltage. Both isolated flyback and boost converters can be made to work like this, but you would probably have to design your own, as the high output current at low voltage may need bigger devices than a commercial design might use. A boost converter would get away with smaller magnetics than a isolated flyback, as part of the output power is delivered directly from the input with a boost, in a flyback it all has to pass through the transformer.

If you're not worried about peak power draw, then you could use a constant voltage limited current output boost converter (the more common type of design available ready built), but that will only be delivering a low power during the low voltage part of the charging process.

Unfortunately recommending specific devices is not allowed on this site, as they would become outdated as time goes on.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic energy and power reasoning**

- A 2200 μF capacitor charged from 0 volts to 59 volts requires an energy input of 3.8291 joules.
- This is based on joules = \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$
- Using a 100% efficient boost converter requires the power delivery to be 38.291 watts to charge the capacitor in 0.1 seconds.

**Efficiency**

I'd be considering a power delivery of maybe 45 to 50 watts taking into account losses in the boost conversion. If you have a 12 volt 5 amp supply (as implied in your question) then this should be doable.

> *I initially wanted to design my own flyback dc-dc converter using an
> Attiny85(will this suffice or do I have to use a dedicated converter
> IC?)*

Yes, this route should be possible without having to resort to dedicated chips. One thing in your favour is that the capacitor will be pre-charged to 12 volts just because of the basic boost topology.

**Potential problems**

However, if you are wanting to discharge the capacitor to 0 volts, you must provide protection so that the 12 volt supply isn't shorted by this action. The problem area arises because when the capacitor is being discharged below 12 volts, the power supply will try and keep it at 12 volts and, will supply potentially diode busting currents to do so.

So, you have to think a little bit more about your requirements.

**Alternative idea**

Maybe a two switch buck-boost circuit is more feasible if you want to avoid the problem mentioned above: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.edn.com/four-switch-buck-boost-converter-in-buck-or-boost-mode-delivers-the-highest-efficiency/).

> *Are there any existing converters that already satisfy the conditions?*

There may be a few but, I can't think of any off-hand. I would go down the design route.

Comment: The two switch boost converter seems less complex than a flyback converter. How would I calculate the value for the inductor and what core size would I use to achieve the 59V voltage conversion?

Comment: @Bob it's a fairly common topology and there should be articles on google so, I'd go down that route rather than expect the full theory presented here. If, after doing some research you still have queries then please do come back and raise a brand-new question on the subject. This also opens up the new question to a broader audience. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> The capacitor will be fully discharged to 0V. To handle the 0V-12V, limiting current seems like the obvious option, unless there is better way.

OK. The usual boost converter topology cannot limit current when Vout<Vin nor isolate input from output, so it is not adequate.

Before looking into topologies, let's polish the requirements a bit. You say you can draw maximum 5A from the 12V battery, which limits output power to 60W minus losses. This is enough to charge the cap in the specified 100ms.

But what should the maximum output current of the DC-DC converter be? A constant power converter has output current proportional to Pout/Vout. So, in the first phase of the charge, when output voltage is low, a buck-boost converter can potentially have a much larger current at the output than at the input. Is there an advantage to oversize the components to allow this?

[image]

So I used a function current source to make a constant power current source with a maximum current limit, which is stepped from 5A to 10A. This higher current is only available for a very short time at the beginning of the charge, after which it becomes limited by available power. So, having 10A output current capability only shortens capacitor charge time by 2 milliseconds out of a total of about 70ms.

So a converter with 5A output is absolutely adequate and there is pretty much no advantage in paying extra for more current.

Now, the topology. You need either a flyback or some form of buck-boost. The latter will most likely be more efficient and not require custom magnetics.

Some ways to make a buck-boost converter are:

- **4-switch buck boost** (per Andy's recommendation)

This can use 4 MOSFETs, of which one or two can be replaced with diodes to trade simpler control against a small loss in efficiency. It can disconnect input from output by turning off the first MOSFET.

- **Or a [SEPIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter) converter**

In this topology, when the MOSFET does not switch, no energy is transferred from input to output. This satisfies the requirement of controlling current during the low voltage part of the charge.

**Tradeoffs**

The 4-switch topology requires two control signals: one for the input MOSFET, and one for the output MOSFET. If synchronous FETs are used instead of diodes, then either we need 4 signals or smart drivers that will handle dead time etc. In addition one of the MOSFETs is on the high side, so if it uses a bootstrapped driver it will need to periodically recharge its bootstrap cap. Thus, control is more complicated.

Analog Devices (ex-Linear Tech) makes various [chips](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc7878.html) that can do the job, or you could roll your own.

On the other hand, SEPIC uses only one low side switch, which is simpler to control, but it places more stress on the components: all the current goes through the middle cap, the FET must handle peak currents of Iin+Iout and peak voltages of Vin+Vout, and the coupled inductor also handles Iin in one winding and Iout in the other, so it will need a bigger core to avoid saturation.

In both cases, I think you should go with a control scheme based on inductor current. SEPIC would be simple: high side current sense on the input, hysteresis comparator, MOSFET driver, and you get a hysteretic DC-DC which will regulate its input current as a sawtooth with the 5A average you want.

For the buck boost, you'd also need to sense inductor current, but both ends will switch to ground, which complicates current sensing.

Comment: Which one do you suggest to use? I am leaning towards using a two-switch buck boost configuration, simply because I already have the majority of the necessary components. I was thinking of using a BJT transistor to drive the mosfet instead of bootstrapped drivers and using the aforementioned ATtiny85, would this work?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd do the control with a AtTiny, it's not really fast enough for this... what kind of control algorithm do you have in mind?

Comment: Could you not account for the lower freq with a larger inductor? I was thinking of using the ATtIny85 like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnUhjnbZ0T8&pp=ygUbZ3JlYXQgc2NvdHQgYm9vc3QgY29udmVydGVy)

Comment: It depends how far back in time you want to travel ;) At 32kHz the inductor is going to be huge and unless you have a way of sensing inductor current there's no way to limit it so it stays within the 5A limit...